# Debug Java test in Eclipse Che

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, eclipse-che

I'm using Eclipse Che 7 hosted on openshift.io for developing a simple java project.
It's possible to debug tests? I can't find a way to launch them. If I open the test view there is

[image: no entry point]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code Java Test Runner extension integration missed.

[1] https://github.com/eclipse/che/issues/14871

Answer (score 2):

It is always possible to use a workaround:

1. Start test in the terminal

`mvn clean install -Dtest=AppTest -Dmaven.surefire.debug`

2. Start a debug session using the following configuration:

```
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Debug (Attach)",
        "request": "attach",
        "hostName": "localhost",
        "port": 5005
    }
```

Comment: oh thank you this evening i will try this workaround!